# SBT doesn't use ssh-based resolver to resolve dependency

Tags: sbt

I have the following definition in my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.bubblefoundry" %% "something" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += {
  val privateKeyFile = new java.io.File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
  Resolver.ssh("Bubble Foundry", "bubblefoundry.com", "/usr/local/repository/") as ("peter", privateKeyFile) withPermissions("0644")
}
```

When sbt tries to resolve the dependency, it fails:

```
[info] Resolving com.bubblefoundry#something_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: com.bubblefoundry#something_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/peter/.ivy2/local/com.bubblefoundry/something_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Bubble Foundry: tried
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.bubblefoundry/something_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/something_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.bubblefoundry#something_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

It appears like it didn't even connect to the server to look for the dependency. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

The dependency has been published (using the same resolver definition) to `/usr/local/repository/com/bubblefoundry/...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution: switch from `ssh` to `sftp`:

```
resolvers += {
  val privateKeyFile = new java.io.File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
  Resolver.sftp("Bubble Foundry", "bubblefoundry.com", "/usr/local/repository/") as ("peter", privateKeyFile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating to sbt 0.13, I can use my private repo by adding the following line to build.sbt

```
resolvers += Resolver.ssh("Company Maven Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")
```

A dialog pops up asking for my github username and password

---

It's a bug!

For example I am using github to host a private/internal maven repo accessed via SSH. I can pull artifacts without any difficultly when using Maven/POM files as you'd expect.

But can't get SBT (0.12.2) to work. Most frustratingly it just says

```
== REPO_NAME: tried
```

Even if I specify invalid authentication or give a bad ssh url it does the same i.e. there is no error reporting.

Spent a few hours researching and trying combinations to no avail. Therefore I suggest SSH repos don't work properly.

Comment: `resolvers += Resolver.ssh("Company Maven Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")` is not working for me... Can you post more details?

Comment: I have a similar issue; for SSH and SFTP resolvers SBT apparently makes no attempt to connect and retrieve artifacts (exactly as Dominic describes). However, if I _do_ provide a `Patterns` (as described by [a comment on SBT issue #1810](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1810#issuecomment-160608021)), it will make an attempt, but it only asks for `ivy.xml` (but not the POM).