# Store dependencies in private GitHub or Bitbucket repo

Tags: scala, sbt

We are using sbt 0.13.9 and we want to use a **private** GitHub repo to store company-wide dependencies.
I try to add a **private** GitHub repo to the resolvers like this:

```
resolvers += Resolver.ssh("Company Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
// or
resolvers += Resolver.ssh("Company Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) as("githubuser")
// or
resolvers += Resolver.ssh("Company Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) as("githubuser", "password")
// or
resolvers += {
    val keyFile: File = new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
    Resolver.ssh("Company Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) as("githubuser", keyFile)
}
// or
resolvers += {
    val keyFile: File = new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
    Resolver.ssh("Company Repo", "git@github.com:company/company-repo.git", "/raw/master")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) as("githubuser", keyFile, "keyFilePassword")
}
```

(For the resolvers where no user and/or no password was supplied a popup appears to enter the username/password.)

However, it is always failing:

```
[warn] ==== Company Maven Repo: tried
[warn]   com.company/my-module_2.11/2.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
```

The location of the files inside the repo are correct, I am 100% sure.

Can sbt handle `git` repos as resolvers at all? Did someone has a working example with a **private** GitHub repo? Bitbucket would be fine too.

Again, the repo is **private** and the repos is a **git** repo, not **http(s)** nor **sftp**.

Oh, and yes, I know bintray, but right now we don't want to pay 45 USD monthly to manage like 3 dependencies for 2 devs.

PS: My configuration is based on examples from

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maven-and-scala/dhzEZ0dR_is and
- [SBT doesn't use ssh-based resolver to resolve dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16360638/810109)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No. I gave up. If you come up with a working solution let me know.

Comment: I'll let you know